# docker stack with mssql and node, how to properly connect to the db?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, docker

I'm trying to build a stack with two containers as a first step, one with the app, one with a MS SQL server. Using no stack, and a container with the SQL server and the app locally works fine, but I can't manage to figure out the proper way to make the containerised app to connect to the DB.

My stack file is as follows :

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  db:
    image: orizon/training-library-sql
    ports:
      - 1443:1443
    networks:
      - backend
  app:
    image: orizon/training-library
    ports: 
      - 4000:4000
    networks:
      - backend
    depends_on:
      - db
    links:
      - db:db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1

networks:
  backend:
```

Db image is based on microsoft/mssql-server-linux:2017-latest and works fine when the app is not in a container and use 'localhost' as hostname.

In the node app, the mssql config is the following:

```
const config = {
  user: '<username>',
  password: '<password>',
  server: 'db', 
  database: 'library',

  options: {
    encrypt: false // Use this if you're on Windows Azure
  }
};
```

And the message I received from node app container :

```
2018-09-07T10:11:57.404Z app ConnectionError: Failed to connect to db:1433 - getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND db
```

---

**EDIT**

Simplified my stackfile and the connectivity now kind of works.
`links` seems deprecated and replaced with `depends_on`

```
version: "3.4"
services:
  db:
    image: orizon/training-library-sql
    ports:
      - 1443:1443
  app:
    image: orizon/training-library
    ports: 
      - 4000:4000
    depends_on:
      - db
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
```

Now the error message changed and let me think it's more of a kind of delay issue. Database container seems like it needs a bit more time to get ready before popping up the app container.
I guess I'm now looking for means to delay connecting to the database either through docker or by code.

Comment: have you tried using actual `ip address` like `127.0.0.1` insted of `localhost` , ,?or `0.0.0.0:port` . .

Comment: When only the DB is in a container and not the app (no stack), localhost works fine. But since I want to build a stack, I should use the network layer provided by docker. As far as I know IPs are dynamic and I should be able to use docker embedded DNS to establish the connection between the two containers. This should the purpose of the link directive. In other words, there is no point to try and connect on localhost.

Comment: oh i see.. i'm not quite understand docker that far. .so i guess im the one who getting an answer here..  thanks for the explanation

Comment: @orizon I am thinking the `app` is starting before `db` (I am doubt about `depends_on`). Separate the two services into two stacks files and deploy `db` stack file first and next `app`. Use the same network in two files.

Comment: Hum, interesting idea... don't know if it would work. But it kind of defeat the very purpose of deploying a stack isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally made it work properly.

See OP for much simpler and effective stack file.
In addition, I added a retry strategy in my app code to let time for the MS SQL server to properly start in the container.

```
function connectWithRetry() {
  return sql.connect(config, (err) => {
    if (err) {
      debug(`Connection to DB failed, retry in 5s (${chalk.gray(err.message)})`);
      sql.close();
      setTimeout(connectWithRetry, 5000);
    } else {
      debug('Connection to DB is now ready...');
    }
 });
}
connectWithRetry();
```

Docker documentation shows a parameter that should answer this (`sequential_deployment: true`) but `docker stack`doesn't allow its usage. Docker documentation itself advise to either manage this issue by code or by adding a delay script.